# Rheem furnace ,RGGE Contour ,communicating ,modulating , 2 stage

Tags: furnace

installed a Rheem RGGE 07EMCKS  Furnace (communicating ) Im getting a d1 code , installed a 2 stage thermostat according to instructions , any ideas what this is ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the relevant page from the manufacturer manual:

[image]

More on the memory card and the D1 error:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: So it sounds like I have no "shared data" ..there's no network to pull shared data from (no communicating condenser or thermostat ) so my IFC and or memory card from the factory has no shared data matched to this unit so a new memory card programmed to this unit must be obtained from "prostock " ..................????

Comment: In this case I only know what the documentation says, same as you.